# Possible to have different Button styles in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a few `OutlineButton`s, and I'd like to be able to have multiple styles (dark, light, small, etc).

I can create a ButtonTheme, but how can I specify the Theme or Style for the buttons as they don't accept either parameter?

ie: I'd like the following two buttons to have different background color:

```
children: {
     OutlineButton(color: Colors.black, child: Text("Hello")), 
     OutlineButton(child:Text("GoodBye"))
 }
```

(The color field is getting ignored as it's using the App Theme's button's background)

Edit: sample code:

```
Widget button(BuildContext context, String icon, String title, [Color backgroundColor = Colors.white, Color textColor = Colors.black] ) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
            child: new OutlineButton(
                key: null,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                borderSide: new BorderSide(color: const Color(0xff666666)),
                highlightedBorderColor: Color(0xFF303030),
                color: backgroundColor,
                onPressed: buttonPressed,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    icon == null ? Container(width: 0, height: 0) :
                    new IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset(icon),
                      iconSize: 32.0,
                      onPressed: () {                       
                      },
                    ),

                    new Expanded(
                      child: new Text(
                        title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.copyWith(color: textColor)

                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ))),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

void buttonPressed() {}
```

and for example, I'm calling it this way:

```
children: {button(null, "Hello", Colors.black, Colors.white), button(null, "Goodbye", Colors.white, Colors.black)}
```

Comment: I'd create reusable custom button widgets or at least reusable ButtonTheme's to wrap buttons with.

Comment: I have a button() method that takes text, textColor and backgroundColor but like I said, even though I'm passing in Colors.black, it's still white (but the textColor gets modified)

Comment: You should post the related code. It's better to create widgets instead of functions that build widgets.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the question with the relevant code.

Comment: I just realized the issue after wasting way too much time on this. The color: parameter is getting ignored if you use an OutlineButton. had to switch to a FlatButton for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use add a `buttonTheme` to your `ThemeData` and then use the **colorSchema** property to define colors (you've a set of 30 customizable colors)  within your widgets like so:

`RaisedButton(color: Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.colorScheme.primary)`

Comment: But how ? Here is my code:

`ThemeData _buildGreenTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
  return base.copyWith(
    buttonTheme: _myButtonThemeData(base.buttonTheme)
  );
}`


Below is button theme data:
`ButtonThemeData _myButtonThemeData(ButtonThemeData base) {
  return base.copyWith();
}`

Comment: You need to pass a new color scheme to your button’s theme `copyWith(colorScheme: ... )`.